# How many different ways to order a dozen two-scoop ice-cream cones?

Tags: combinatorics

> An ice cream store sells 30 different flavours of ice cream and it offers a choice of 3 different kinds of cones. In how many ways can we order a dozen two-scoop ice cream cones if any two of them in one order must differ at least by a flavor or by the kinds of cones?

How would I go about solving this question? I was having difficulty working around the statement:

"any two of them in one order must differ at least by a flavour"

EDIT:

So assuming that (vanilla, chocolate) and (chocolate, vanilla) counts as a repetition, would I be correct in saying that the number of possible ice cream cones would be C(30, 2) * 3?

And assuming that the order i mentioned above doesn't count as a repetition, and is valid as two different choices, would the correct calculation instead be 30*30*3 for the number of valid choices for ice cream cones?

EDIT 2: But then again, it says must differ by flavour OR by kinds of cones so do i tally them up as two separate cases and then add up the total as the number of possible cone choices?

Comment: Does (cone with chocolate and vanilla) = (cone with vanilla and chocolate)?

Comment: i.e., does the order of scooping matter?

Comment: @Mike See I would think so because it says any two in one order. This was the part I found kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First, enumerate the number of possible ice cream cones, and call in $n$.

Then, there are ${n}\choose{12}$ possible orders.

Comment: the enumeration of the number of possible ice cream cones is what I am mainly having problems with. I am fairly sure that my edited response is wrong somewhere but I am not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the scoops matters -

There will be $_{30}$P$_{2}$ ways for the scoops and $3$ ways for the cones

$\therefore$ Number of distinct ice-creams = $3(_{30}$P$_{2})$

$\therefore$ Number of ways to order $12$ distinct ice creams = $\binom{3(_{30}P_{2})}{12}$